# How to change the Google Map search result position?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is the code which I'm using to display search-box inside Google map.

```
function setSearchbox(map) {
    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('searchLocation');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });
    var markers = [];
    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function (marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];
        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function (place) {
            var icon = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(40, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };
            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
            }));
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                // Only geocodes have viewport.
                bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
}
```

And the output is,

[image]

Is it possible to move the search result box to just above the search box (drop-up instead of drop-down)?

I've gone through lot of reference website, but no luck.

Comment: You want to make it "drop up" rather than drop down?

Comment: Yes, I want to make it as drop up.

Comment: @geocodezip There is a CSS work-around, but is there a proper solution available to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "proper" solution, if you have a solution that works for you (and doesn't depend on undocumented behavior), use it.

Comment: What I meant is, if there is a an option in the API then it will be a proper one, If I write css then there is changes to get the wiped when a new update is available in the API. I'll add the work-around as an answer. Many thanks.

Comment: there is no API-based option